# Code sharing between small student group

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm currently in college, and we work in groups of three to create small python projects on a weekly basis.

We code with Eclipse and PyDev but we've got a problem when it comes to sharing our work. We end up sending an infinite stream of emails with compressed projects.

What we need is a way to keep the source code updated and we need to be able to share it between us. (on both Windows and Linux) What do you recommend?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use source control - mercurial, git, subversion.

Comment: If its only sharing what you're doing maybe you could start using Dropbox.

Comment: To advance the Dropbox idea it may be possible to share a Subversion etc. repository using Dropbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) in conjunction with [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/).

Comment: i've looked around at all the options and Mercurial looks ok and Bitbucket seems the most appropriate for our goal. We're all in favor of open software, but we'd like to keep the projects private until we hand them over for evaluation just to keep things fair. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use Git and [Github](https://github.com/). This way your code is in version control ( which is a good practice) and it can be shared with other people in your project through github. ( github was built with good git integration).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using a version control system.

Git might be good for you - it doesn't require a central server and there is also support for Windows these days.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a control version server (SVN for instance). You will be able to commit the changes and update the local version of your code  to the current server version.

It is for free:

`http://code.google.com/`

You should set up your repo and share your work! :-)

I hope it helps.